# Matrix-NMS mechanism

Tags: machine-learning

For [SOLOv2: Dynamic, Faster and Stronger](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.10152.pdf#page=5) , could anyone explain how both decay factor and decremented functions make matrix-NMS **parallel** in terms of implementation ?

[image: matrix NMS]

Answer (score 0):

The first two (Soft NMS and Greedy NMS) require an ordering of the detection scores, whereas Matrix NMS uses the IoU score itself to compute the weighting factor directly. That is, the weight attributed to any given detection is not dependent on the IoUs of other detections.